# Visualizar ou ocultar um elemento com códigos javascript utilizando o style.display

Tags: javascript

Montei um código que quando a condição for verdadeira mostre o componente na tela e quando for falsa esconde o componente. Quando a condição é falsa na primeira vez ele esconde, mas mudando para condição verdadeira o componente não aparece.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
function VerificarDeposito(){

    if ($('#DadosComplementares').val()=="SIM"){

        document.getElementById('Painel4').style.display = 'true';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('Painel4').style.display = 'none'; 
    };
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde! Vi que desmarcou minha resposta. Isso não tem problema algum, mas se puder dizer se não funcionou eu gostaria de melhorá-la. ObG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o valor do elemento nunca for alterado, ele nunca voltará a aparecer. Altere o valor do elemento para alternar a visibilidade:

```
function VerificarDeposito(){
    if ($('#DadosComplementares').val()=="SIM"){
        $('#DadosComplementares').val("NÃO");
        $('#Painel4').show();
    }else{
        $('#DadosComplementares').val("SIM");
        $('#Painel4').hide(); 
    };
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function VerificarDeposito(){
    if ($('#DadosComplementares').val()=="SIM"){
        $('#DadosComplementares').val("NÃO");
        $('#Painel4').show();
    }else{
        $('#DadosComplementares').val("SIM");
        $('#Painel4').hide(); 
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="VerificarDeposito()">Verificar</button>
<br>
<input type="text" value="NÃO" id="DadosComplementares" />
<br>
<div id="Painel4">
   painel4
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se está usando **jQuery**, por que usar o `getElementById`?

Pode usar o `show` e `hide` do **jQuery** também, assim:

```
if ($('#DadosComplementares').val()=="SIM") {
    $('#Painel4').show();
} else {
    $('#Painel4').hide(); 
};
```

Comment: interessante como as pessoas votam na resposta como negativa sem ao menos informar o que não é útil nela

Comment: Isso é verdade, eu tento melhorar a pergunta para ver se os votos mudam, mas esta difícil.